# How can I refresh React Functional component?

Tags: reactjs

Now I'm using React Functional Component and going to display about variable.

```
let bundles_data = [];
const SelectExistNFCType = (props) => {
   const setAdd = async () => {
       ...
        data.map((value, index) => {
            bundles_data.push(value)
        })
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to display bundles_data's value when calling setAdd  function.
Now the bundles_data is changing, but can't display immediately.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Please the state of React.

```
const SelectExistNFCType = (props) => {
   const [bundlesData, setBundlesData] = React.useState([]);
   const setAdd = async () => {
        ...
        data.map((value, index) => {
            setBundlesData([...bundlesData, value]);
        })
        ...
     }
}
```